# Find customers with more than 1 order grouped by day

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know how many customers placed more than 1 order, grouped by day.
But I want to exclude orders that have been cancelled.

- I have a customer table with customers
- I have a customer_order table with orders (when an order is cancelled
  it stays in the customer_order table)
- I have an order_item table (where original orders are, and also
  cancelled orders, cancelled orders get a new credit order, and the
  original order id appears in the id_credit_order row of the credit
  order)

I want something like this:

```
date  |  no of customers with 1 order  |  no of customers with 2 orders  |  no of customers with 3 order  |  etc.
```

But I want no count if the original order has been cancelled!

**I have now this query, but its definitely not enough, does someone know how to get my result? thanks!**

```
SELECT DATE(co.date_order), COUNT(co.id_customer)
FROM customer_order co
GROUP BY DATE(co.date_order)
ORDER BY DATE(co.date_order) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is slightly misleading, as you first ask for the number of customers with more than one order, then you ask for the number of customer with each of 1, 2, 3... orders.

Here's something that will give you the numbers, but unpivoted. You'll need to put the right column name in for o.id

```
Select -- outer query takes each order count and counts how many customers have that many
    co.date_order,
    co.customer_order_count,
    count(*) as customer_count
From (
    Select -- inner query counts how many valid orders each customer has
        o.date_order,
        o.id_customer,
        count(*) as customer_order_count
    From
        customer_order o
    Where
        o.id_credit_order is null and -- rule out credit orders
        not exists ( -- rule out orders with related credit orders
            select
                'x'
            from
                customer_order c
            where
                c.id_credit_order = o.id -- column name isn't mentioned in the question
        )
    Group By
        o.date_order,
        o.id_customer
    ) co
Group By
    co.date_order,
    co.customer_order_count
Order By
    co.date_order desc,
    co.customer_order_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT DATE(co.date_order), COUNT(co.id_customer)
FROM customer_order co
WHERE co.Cancelled = 0
GROUP BY DATE(co.date_order)
HAVING COUNT(co.id_customer) >= 1
ORDER BY DATE(co.date_order) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Change the WHERE to reflect how you cancel orders.

```
SELECT DATE(co.date_order), COUNT(co.id_customer)
FROM customer_order co
WHERE co.cancelled = 0
GROUP BY DATE(co.date_order)
HAVING COUNT(co.id_customer) > 0
ORDER BY DATE(co.date_order) DESC;
```